# MathJaX breaks tables, can't scroll to see whole post

Tags: bug, mathjax, mobile-safari

On sites with MathJaX, such as Math.SE or MathOverflow, occasionallythe window posts are contained in 'breaks' and I can't scroll to see the whole thing - this makes them impossible to read. Examples include [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/218089/40804) ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnbsY.jpg)), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1580364/98602) ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyuag.jpg)) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220032/are-dagger-categories-truly-evil) ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dqUx.jpg)). In most of these (but it doesn't seem the last one?) there are MathJaX formulas that are longer than fit in the screen, which seem to permanently break the boundaries of the post.

I'm using an iPhone 5s with (what I think is) iOS version 8.0.2.